# Erro Eclipse durante builds após update para ubuntu 22.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, maven

Atualizei recentemente o meu ubuntu do 20.04 para o 22.04, desde então estou recebendo esse erro toda vez que mando o eclispe fazer a build do projeto:

Já desinstalei por completo o eclipse, inclusive excluindo todas as pastas e atalhos, workspace, etc... e instalando ele de novo.

Segue erro:

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Maven
> Project Builder' on project '...'. loader constraint violation: loader
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @37c6bbec wants to
> load class org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject. A different class
> with the same name was previously loaded by
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @212d8133.
> (org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject is in unnamed module of loader
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @212d8133, parent
> loader 'platform')

Versão utilizada:

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)
Build id: 20220908-1902
OS: Linux, v.5.15.0-50-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.33, WebKit 2.36.8
Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
Java runtime version: 18.0.2.1+1
Java version: 18.0.2.1
```

Comment: Eu também estou tendo o mesmo problema. Por enquanto, pensei em trabalhar sem esses "recursos", clique com o botão direito do mouse em executar o maven funciona ... também está afetando as ferramentas do Spring. JDK 17.

Comment: Eu posso ter quebrado a nova instalação adicionando JBoss Tools e então STS

Eu também não falo bem/qualquer português ;-(